# Updating a specific field of object state in React

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-state

I am using a React functional component where I want to update only a specific field of the state and retain the other values like before. Here's the state initialization -

```
const[value, setValue] = React.useState({
     a: "5",
     b: "6"
});
```

I wish to only update value of 'a' to something else, let's say 7 (whilst retaining the same value for 'b'). Currently I am doing this -

```
setValue(currValue => ({
   ...currValue,
   a: "7"
}))
```

Is this wrong ? If yes, what's the correct way of doing it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.

That's the proper way for updating the state based on the current value of the state. It's called the functional form of the `setState` call.

```
setState((prevState) => {
  // Do something with prevState
  return newState; // Be aware to not mutate the prevState directly
});
```

Examples:

```
// Array

setState((prevState) => {
  const newState = Array.from(prevState);
  newState.push('foo');
  return newState;
});

// Object

setState((prevState) => {
  return({
    ...prevState,
    foo: 'bar'
  });
});
```

The main thing is that the object/array reference needs to change!